# Error when trying to access Message Tracking in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

When I try to access the Message Tracking functionality of Exchange 2010 it redirects me to OWA to login and then I get the below error:

```
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Detailed Error Information

Module: StaticFileModule
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler: StaticFile
Error Code: 0x80070001

Requested URL: https://mailserver:443/owa/auth/owaauth.dll
Physical Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\owa\auth\owaauth.dll
Logon Method: Basic
Logon User: username
```

I've looked around for a solution but haven't found anybody with the same exact issue I'm having which included a working resolution.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathias answer appeared to be what I was looking for but after scheduling a maintenance window and doing the work, the commands listed did not work with Exchange 2010.

I was able to get the issue resolved by recreating the virtual directories for Exchange Control Panel, but did it through the Exchange Management Console by performing the below steps:

1. Open EMC
2. Microsoft Exchange > Microsoft Exchange On-Premises
3. Server Configuration > Client Access
4. Select the server name which you're having the problem with
5. Select the tab in the lower half for Exchange Control Panel
6. Select "Reset Virtual Directory"
7. Browse to the necessary vDir (in this case, ECP (Default Web Site)) > Next
8. Set your log location (I used the default) > Next
9. Review the steps that will be taken > Reset
10. Reset IIS - Open an admin cmd session and type in "iisreset /noforce"

Once I followed these steps, things started working once again.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no one had the exact same problem on Exchange Server 2010, but somebody had on Exchange Server 2007: http://forums.msexchange.org/m_1800506166/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#1800506175

Try removing and recreating the OWA and ECP vDirs as described in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941201) under Resolution -> For Exchange Server 2010 -> **"Step 1: Delete and then re-create the Outlook Web Access-related virtual directories"**

Comment: How risky is this procedure? OWA is working elsewhere so I'd like to minimize the impact to end users. I'm guessing this will need to be completed during a scheduled maintenance window.

Comment: In itself it is not risky. Should you be unable to recreate the directories, it probably indicates a far more serious underlying problem. If you only have 1 CAS, it will mean a total loss of service for the time in between removing and recreating the vDirs (a matter of minutes). But yes, in that case, I'd probably call a service window on the environment.

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin: Uh, yeah, you'd want to do this in a in a scheduled maintenance window.  Good practice for any major or potentially major-impact change.  Should be pretty low-risk, but I'm guessing your users might notice the absence of webmail while you do it.

Comment: We have multiple CAS servers so I will look into directing all traffic to the server that is not being worked on during the maintenance window. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Oldy but still a top result for this issue, and I resolved it a slightly different way.

Check under server config>client access>Exchange control panel>properties of ecp. Check the URL's  - There's a good change you have your internal URL pointing to /OWA rather than /ECP, as that's where the EMC pulls it from when you go to message tracking. EMC needs a restart for it to take effect.